# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_header'

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm encountering and error on extracting data from db and converting it to excel, I'm using [django-excel](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library for the task.

I'm extracting `user.email` from my `ClientContact` model, and I'm creating service call that creates `excel` file, but I'm facing an Attribute error - `'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_header'`, so can someone help me understand this so I can fix it, thanks.

The model field from `ClientContact`, from which I need to extract email:

```
class ClientContact(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

`FormView` for making an excel file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django import forms

import django_excel as excel

from clients.models import ClientContact


class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    pass


class ExportClientsMailXls(FormView):
    template_name = 'clients/export_email/export_email.html'
    form_class = UploadFileForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if request.user.is_staff:
            return self.render_to_response(
                self.get_context_data(form=form,
                                      can_submit=True,))
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if request.user.is_staff:
            if form.is_valid():
                emails = ClientContact.objects.all()
                for email in emails:
                    return email.user.email
                column_name = ['contact_email']
                return excel.make_response_from_array(emails,
                                                      column_name,
                                                      "xls",
                                                      file_name="export_client_mail")
            else:
                return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: did you looked at   
`for email in emails:  
      return email.user.email`
I think here is your mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `post` method as follows, because you are returning before converting to excel

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if request.user.is_staff:
            if form.is_valid():
                emails = ClientContact.objects.all()
                # Look here
                list_of_emails = []
                for email in emails:
                    email_lst = []
                    email_lst.append(email.user.email)
                    list_of_emails.append(email_lst)
                return excel.make_response_from_array(list_of_emails,
                                                      "xls",
                                                      file_name="export_client_mail",
                                                      status=200)
                else:
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
            else:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I see where are you getting at, but now I'm facing `'list' object has no attribute 'lower'` - Attribute error

Comment: @PetarP could you update your question with example of excel which you want to produce?

Comment: well i don't have and example, it will be only one row with `user.email` from `ClientContact`, this is all I've got

Comment: @PetarP please try updated version, sorry but I can't test it

Comment: `column_name` was giving me trouble, It's ok now, I've got my file, thanks for the suggested stuff it have helped me, rookie mistake

Comment: @PetarP I've updated answer so it could help others. I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139147/discussion-between-latsha-and-petarp).